# xUnit параметризованный тест с объектом

Tags: c#, xunit

Всем привет. Пытаюсь написать параметризованный тест для приложения ASP.NET Core MVC, с использованием xUnit. Например, есть unit-тест вида:

```
[Theory]
public void ExampleTest(Person person)
{
  //DoSmth()
}
```

Вопрос заключается в том, как на вход тесту передать список объектов Person? Т.е. чтобы один и тот же тест прошел на разных объектах типа Person. Например, если аргументы теста имеют простой тип, то можно в атрибутах метода прописать несколько атрибутов [InlineData(...)], но как быть в случае сложного типа?

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(30, "Bob")]
[InlineData(20, "Alice")]
public void ExampleTest(int age, string name)
{
    var person = new Person(age, name);

    //DoSmth()
}
```

В атрибуте `InlineData` задаём данные, из которых в тестовом методе конструируется объект нужного типа.

---

Другой способ - используем атрибут `ClassData`:

```
[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(PersonTestData))]
public void ExampleTest(Person person)
{
    //DoSmth()
}
```

В этом атрибуте указываем класс-источник данных:

```
public class PersonTestData : IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new object[] { new Person(30, "Bob") };
        yield return new object[] { new Person(20, "Alice") };
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

---

Третий способ - источником данных является свойство этого же класса:

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(PersonData))]
public void ExampleTest(Person person)
{
    Assert.NotNull(person.Name);
    Assert.True(person.Age > 0);
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> PersonData =>
    new List<object[]>
    {
        new object[] { new Person(30, "Bob") },
        new object[] { new Person(20, "Alice") }
    };
```